Lengths of paths between vertices in a directed graph
Let $G$ be a finite directed graph and $v,u$ be two vertices of $G$. I am interested in the following question: For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a path of length $n$ from $v$ to $u$? I know that we can take the adjacency matrix of $G$, compute $n$-th power and look at its $vu$-coefficient. However, I don't need the number of paths, just existence. For example: if there is a path of length $l$ from $v$ to $u$ and a cycle at $u$ of length $m$, then all values $n=l+km$, $k\geq 0$ are admissible. Of course, there could be other pairs $(l,m)$. I think one can describe possible values of $n$ by finitely many rules of the form $n=l+km$, $k\geq 0$. Is it true and how to compute such a description?
Edit: I think I got it. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$. Then we can consequently compute powers of $A$ and each time replace a coefficient $>0$ with $1$. We get a sequence of $01$-matrices, it is eventually periodic. Then we can deduce numbers $r_1,\ldots,r_l$ and $m$ such that $n$ is admissible iff $n=r_i+km$ for some $i$ and $k$.

Why not just look at whether the $vu$ component of the $n$th power of $G$’s adjacency matrix is nonzero?

Because this requires computing $n$th power, and this doesn't give a description of possible values of $n$.
